# How to optimize filter logic

Tags: optimization, pine-script

hello how to optimize this code please:

```
OpenLong = if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongHmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongHmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongHmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongSmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongHmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == true and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and SMA[backfiltervalue]<SMA
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongHmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongSmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongHmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongHmaFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == true and activehmafilter == true and activeRsiFilter == true
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours and OpenLongSmaFilter and OpenLongHmaFilter and OpenLongRsiFilter
    else if activeBackFilter == false and activesmafilter == false and activehmafilter == false and activeRsiFilter == false
        SMA < EMA and SMA < outCours and EMA < outCours**
```

Many ty for help in advance !

Answer (score 0):

See how filters are implemented in the [Backtesting & Trading Engine [PineCoders]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/):

```
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————— 4. Filters ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————— Filter 1: Random
Filter1Long = FilterType1? round( f_pseudo_random_number(FilterType1Freq, 0.5))==1 : true
Filter1Short = FilterType1? round( f_pseudo_random_number(FilterType1Freq, 0.6))==1 : true
// ————— Filter 2: External indicator (thx to @RicardoSantos and @theheirophant via @simpelyfe for the idea)
// Indicator must supply us with: Bull=1.0, Bear=-1.0.
Filter2Long = FilterType2? ExternalIndie==1.0 : true
Filter2Short = FilterType2? ExternalIndie==-1.0 : true
...
// ————— Filter 11: MA Squize
Filter11Long = FilterType11? MASqzBull : true
Filter11Short = FilterType11? MASqzBear : true

// ———————————————————— Assemble filters
FilterLongOK = false
FilterShortOK = false
FilterLongOK := Filter1Long and Filter2Long and Filter3Long and Filter4Long and Filter5Long and Filter6Long and Filter7Long and Filter8Long and Filter9Long and Filter10Long and Filter11Long
FilterShortOK := Filter1Short and Filter2Short and Filter3Short and Filter4Short and Filter5Short and Filter6Short and Filter7Short and Filter8Short and Filter9Short and Filter10Short and Filter11Short
```